# Show Win32 popup menu with PNG icons from resources

Tags: c++, winapi

It's been a long time since I've had to deal with Win32 menus. I need to add some PNG icons to a Win32 context popup menu. Naturally, I want to preserve PNG transparency and all the per-pixel-alpha in the process. Is this possible?

I was thinking on using `SetMenuItemBitmaps`. Is that the way to go?

I imported my PNGs as "PNG" resources but I can't seem to load them neither with `LoadBitmap` nor with `LoadImage`. I found some suggestions about using `Gdi+` but obviously I won't be drawing the menu - the system will.

There seems to be a way to get a `HBITMAP` from a Gdi+ `Bitmap` but it looks as if all the alpha is getting lost in the process. AFAIK, a `HBITMAP` can happily host alpha information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need GDI+ to load a PNG. Then you need to create a 32-bit alpha bitmap of the correct size, create a Graphics on the bitmap, and use DrawImage to copy the PNG to the bitmap. That gives you a bitmap with an alpha channel.

Something like this:

```
Image*  pimgSrc = Image::FromFile("MyIcon.png"L, FALSE);
Bitmap* pbmpImage = new Bitmap(
    iWidth, iHeight, 
    PixelFormat32bppARGB
);
Graphics* pgraphics = Graphics::FromImage(bmpImage))
{
    // This draws the PNG onto the bitmap, scaling it if necessary.
    // You may want to set the scaling quality 
    graphics->DrawImage(
        imageSrc,
        Rectangle(0,0, bmpImage.Width, bmpImage.Height),
        Rectangle(0,0, imgSrc.Width, imgSrc.Height),
        GraphicsUnitPixel
    );
}
// You can now get the HBITMAP from the Bitmap object and use it.
// Don't forget to delete the graphics, image and bitmap when done.
```

Comment: Thank you. I have managed to work it out in the end. It appears that no `Graphics` drawing was necessary. I was able to get the bitmap by just calling `Bitmap::GetHBITMAP` after first loading from resources. Now I am having a different problem related to actually showing the bitmap on the menu. Will post a new question...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use icon instead?

Here are my reasons for using icons instead of PNGs:

1. The Win32 API has good support icons, and it relatively much easier to draw icons, since GDI+ is not required.
2. Icons also support 8-bit transparency (just like PNGs).
3. Icons can be any size in pixels (just like PNGs).
4. Icons can easily be embedded in the executable as a resource.
5. Icons can be edited via Visual Studio.

To load an icon from a resource or a file use:

```
LoadImage()
```

To draw the icon, use:

```
DrawIcon() or DrawIconEx()
```

Comment: Thanks for a lengthy answer but you missed the point. Even if I wanted to switch to icons, there is still an issue of assigning an icon (with transparency) to the standard menu. I do not want to do owner-drawing and `DrawIcon`. Btw, PNGs can be just as easily embedded as a resource.